# Backend send queue read access

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, send-email

Last week we had an issue where during the scheduling of a send, we experienced a timeout error. Upon refreshing my browser I looked at the tracking tab and no email appeared as "scheduled." However, it was scheduled, we just couldn't see it.

Support said it was added to the "backend send queue" but not the tracking tab.

My question is, is there any way outside of the UI to see if there is something actually scheduled? ome sort of API integration or JS script I can run to check the any sends scheduled under that MID or something?  Thx!